# SAS infile truncating long numbers with E

Tags: sas

I have searched around a bit and found some people asking a similar question, but I have not found an answer I can make work.

I have tab delimited .txt files which I need to read in to a SAS database. The files contain a serial number which is 18 numbers long so SAS imports this as "5.2231309E17".

Ideally SAS would import all the fields as if they were text, not numbers.

To add a complexity to this, the import files have 2 different formats, these are only visible once the file is open, I cannot tell which format the file is from the name. Also there are no column names in the file. So I don't know which column is which until I have read in the file.

Currently my starting point is:

```
data Readin;
infile foo dsd dlm='09'x truncover; 
input item1-item25;
run;
```

foo is the file something like 'c:\myfile.txt'

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues here.  One is that the "9.234E17" is displaying in scientific notation, and two that you are reading in numbers that can't be stored exactly as numbers anyway.

First, this is how the BEST12. format works, which is the default numeric format for things like this.  It's not truncating it in a meaningful way; if you simply change the format, to BEST32. for example, it will display the entire number, within the limits of precision, and it will always act as if it were the full number, again within the limits of precision; if I took 12345678, formatted BEST6., it would display as 1.23e7, but if I said `if x=12345678 then do; put x; end;`, it would put x, as it would be exactly equal to that value.

However, that last part is important, and the second part of your problem.  You can't store 18 digit number precisely; 15 digits is the largest you can store precisely in Windows and similar Intel type environments, slightly different results on mainframes.  So you definitely need these to be stored as character, unless you don't care about the last few digits (sounds like you do).

If you have a (anything)-delimited file, your best bet is to simply write a data step to read them in, at which point you can assign them as character yourself.  Don't use `proc import` for most text files, unless they're really easy impossible to screw up sorts of things.  What you can do is look at your log after `PROC IMPORT` ran, and copy that log into a program; then make adjustments to turn the serial number into a character field (and anything else you want to fix).

Comment: Not how I would have liked to do it, but works well. Used the PROC IMPORT to get the parameters correct then created two infile statements to handle the different file types.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, I was trying to import a file that had a 20 digit long field, one workaround i found for this was, opening the file in Excel and changing the attribute of the column from general to number, then when i imported the file, it was imported as a number and not in scientific notation

Comment: I have seen other people do this, and I am sure this would work, but I want to include this as part of an automated process so need SAS to be able to handle it itself. Thank you though.

Comment: SAS could not possibly correctly import a 20 digit field, because SAS would not be able to store that number accurately; the maximum you can store completely is 15 digits.

Comment: You can, if the column type is character, it still imports it as scientific notation, if you change the type in excel to number from general. It imports it without scientific notation